# Create web site with node.js and publish it(not localhost)?

Tags: node.js

I made a web site with node.js.I will buy a domain and want to publish my site;but i dont know how do this.I always work with localhost.I published a web site(made with php).

Comment: Do you want to host it yourself (you must be able to forward port 80) or use a service like AWS?

Comment: I dont want to host i myself.

Comment: You'll need to point your domain's A record to your node server IP, that's basically it.

Comment: _i dont know how do this_ What specific problem do you face ?

Comment: Hosts dont support node js in Turkey so i must install node js manually.

Comment: Could you use a service like Heroku ?